# Save (and exclude) posts from loop to use in another loop on page

Tags: wp-query, loop

I'm trying to display related posts on my taxonomy page, but not sure how to work out the second loop. I have shared taxonomys among posts, and on this page it shows post type A with tags "Light".

Some of the posts with tags "Light" are NOT post type A. So I have the following:

```
<?php $related = array(); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if(get_post_type() == 'Type_B' || get_post_type() == 'Type_C'){
        array_push($related, $post);
        continue;
    } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This works fine. But then later down on the page where I want to loop type B and C I thought it would be simple to make a similar loop. But the wp_query array seems to be special? Even though my array contains posts.

```
if($related->have_posts()){
    while($related->have_posts()) { $related->the_post();
        print_r($post);
    }
}
```

I get the following error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function have_posts() on array`

I've tried `$relatedList = new WP_query($related);` but it's not right. Any tips?

**Edit:** Hm seems like I might have been going about this the wrong way. Where I have my second loop I still have access to the main loop, so I could just do an reveres post-if-check there. **Is this what I should be doing?** (code-standard-wise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that `$wp_query` is not an array. It's and instance of [`WP_Query` class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). That's why it has some methods like `have_posts`, `the_post`, and so on...

On the other hand, your `$related` is normal PHP array, so it doesn't have any methods - so if you try to call any method, you're getting fatal error.

Since the posts are already added to `$related` array, the easies way to deal with them would be to just loop through that array:

```
if ( ! empty($related) ) {
    foreach ( $related as $post) {
        print_r($post);
        // you can't use template tags in here unless you use setup_postdata function
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, thank you! Of course, forgot the basic programming stuff right there smh.